# Why aren't Stripe events firing and not being received by webhook?

Tags: heroku, stripe-payments, webhooks

I've tested my webhooks locally, using the CLI, and they work fine. However, when I took the webhooks live and deployed them to Heroku, and went into "live" mode on Stripe (which I assume is necessary to be able to use live webhooks), Stripe just doesn't fire events at all, they don't appear in the dashboard, webhook endpoint doesn't get any requests, nothing; for example, no `account.updated` when a I try to create a Connected account, or no `checkout.session.complete` when I try to complete a Checkout purchase. Is there a step I've perhaps missed when taking my webhooks online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this issue myself- a few ideas:

- Make sure you are configured correctly in the dashboard, eg. only flip the "Test Mode" switch if you are looking at test data
- Make sure you have the endpoints set up for both live and testing. You have to add them each time
- Double-check that you're using the correct signing secret. The signing secret will be differnt for live, production testing, and local testing, even if you're using the same endpoint.

For example:

- [Production] Live - Endpoint = https://www.example.com/webhooks. Signing secret = xyz
- [Production] Testing - Endpoint = https://www.example.com/webhooks. Signing secret = abc
- [Local] Testing - Endpoint = localhost:5000/webhooks. Signing secret = efg

Comment: The second bullet point is actually what solved the issue, I wish these disrepancies between live & test mode aren't made more obvious in the dashboard. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Stripe Connect, webhooks won't fire if you selected the wrong `type`.

When you set up a new webhook, there's a radio button that asks whether it's for 'Account' or 'Connect':

[image]

I had correctly selected 'Connect' when I set up my 'test' webhooks, but I had accidentally selected 'Account' for the production ones, which is why they weren't firing at all.

So just double check that you correctly selected 'Connect' or 'Account'. I don't think there's a way to alter it on existing endpoints, so I just created identical new ones with the correct type and everything suddenly worked as expected.

[image]